# Google CSE doesn't returns the same results as "real" google search

Tags: python, google-custom-search

I'm trying to use the google custom search and i cant find out how to mimic the "real" google results.

I'm writing exactly the same query in both google and the google cse method and i'm getting totally diffrent results.
Anyone can tell me how i can optimize the search results to be identical to google's results?

MyCode :

```
service = build("customsearch", "v1",
            developerKey=key)

res = service.cse().list(
          q=random_query_string,
          cx=cx,
      ).execute()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends how the engine (cx) you are issuing the requests against is configured. Usually you have "sites to search" added in your engine and therefore the search returns only results from that list.

Comment: lets say i configured my site in the query_string, it's still the same problem, for example: "site:..."

Comment: lets say it this way, how i need to configure my search engine in order to get the same results as i get in the normal google search?

Comment: I think you won't be able to replicate exactly Google Search, as this way Google would be out of business. There are only 2 use cases supported by GCS: site search or topical search. Each of them let you perform a search on a limited domain of sites in the index and not replicate full search.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 use cases supported by GCS: site search or topical search. Each of them let you perform a search on a limited domain of sites in the index and not replicate full search.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get the 'real' google results. As per this issue https://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=43

[image]